# Ubuntu Auto logout issue from GUI?

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

It's working fine from TERMINAL mode but when i change terminal mode to GUI mode in ubuntu, and enter password for user name it'l again logout, my password is correct. But always redirect to again logout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are experiencing problem with gdm or ligthdm. Can you check their status.

```
service gdm status
```

Sometimes the display manager would have crashed, you can check this in `/var/crash`.  If you are running Ubuntu using VirtualBox try re-installing VBox tools.